# Example Xamarin MasterDetail Data Binding to Selected Item

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am learning Xamarin by doing tests with the basic MasterDetail example that is given by visual studio when you do an Add -> New Item... -> Master Detail Page on a solution.   In this example the Master Page data binds to a list of items in a view model and when one is selected it displays the detail page.  My issue is that the default detail page is empty and doesn't show how to bind to the selected item.  So my question is how to modify this basic detail page..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.WireFrameDetail"
             Title="Detail">
    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <Label Text="This is a detail page. To get the 'triple' line icon on each platform add a icon to each platform and update the 'Master' page with an Icon that references it."/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

What I want to do is just bind to the item that is selected on the master page and display the Title property in the label text to say something like, "This is a detail page for {Binding Title}."  I have tried a number of things but it seems as though this page has no data binding by default, I am suspecting it needs to be injected as part of the ItemSelected process but I was hoping it would be automatically bound by the framework.

So my question is, what do I need to add to accomplish this simple binding to the item selected on the master page?

Comment: You could bind both pages to the same VM and display the selected item that way.  Or pass the selected item as a parameter to the detail page.

Comment: In your detail page constructor, you can always pass the value of your selected item and then bind the value to your title property in the constructor itself.

Comment: These comments got me to the right place, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Passing_Data_when_Navigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others posted in the comments the ways to do this are via constructor, parameter passing, and binding injection.  These are outlined here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Passing_Data_when_Navigating